# XPATH: how to get child nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

i have following html

```
      <ul class="enh-toggle">
         <li>
        <a href="#design">Design<sup>1</sup><span class="accordion"></span></a>
        <ul id="design">
               <li>
                   <strong>Dimensions</strong>
                    <ul><li>length:12.3cm</li></ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
```

i use the following code to get ul[id='design']

```
HTMLNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='enh-toggle']//ul[@id='design']");
```

this just work perfect...

now my question is how can i get the strong tag text. i use the following code but it don't works

```
string text = node.SelectSingleNode("/li/strong").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variation on the "li/strong" answers:

```
string text = node.SelectSingleNode("./li/strong").InnerText;
```

Comment: I'd prefer this version because it explicitly denotes starting at the current context instead of the root.

Answer (score 1):

A single slash in XPath is the root of the document. You just want to select the direct descendants, so you don't need to give a context:

```
string text = node.SelectSingleNode("li/strong").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should just be:

```
string text = node.SelectSingleNode("li/strong").InnerText;
```

..without the leading `/`.